# How many leading digits in $v(x)$ are guarenteed to agree with those of $f(x)$, for any $0\leq x \leq 381$?

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Consider the piece-wise constant interpolation of the function $$f(x)=\sin(x), 0\leq x\leq 381$$ at points $x_i=ih$ where $h=0.1$. Thus, our interpolant satisfies $$v(x)=\sin(ih), (i-0.5)h\leq x \leq (i+0.5)h$$ for $i=0,1,\dots , 3810.$

**How many leading digits in $v(x)$ are guarenteed to agree with those of $f(x)$, for any $0\leq x \leq 381$?**

I am not sure what it means by leading digits... Does it mean that the constant interpolant begins at the same spot as $\sin(x)$? I am also not sure how $v(x)=\sin(ih), (i-0.5)h\leq x \leq (i+0.5)h$ is constant... Thank you for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, $\sin(5)\approx 0.08717557$  The interpolation says $v(x)\approx 0.08717557$ for any $x$ such that $4.95 \lt x \le 5.05$, but $f(x)$ will vary over the range.  $f(x)$ will be close to $v(x)$ over that range.  You are expected to figure out how much they can differ.  If they cannot differ by more than $0.001$ you would say that the first three digits agree-the first three after the decimal point.  Yes, they can change because of carries, but this is a rough idea of how good the approximation is.  In fact the error can be larger than that-I leave that to you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into that. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I found that the error bound was h/2 in the previous part since error of a constant interpolation is $\frac{h}{2}max|f'(x)|=\frac{h}{2}$... Therefore is it 0.1/2=0.05 the max error? So then the interpolation would be accurate to the first digit for all x?

Comment: Yes, you have it right.

Comment: I was thinking about this a bit more. If the error can be as much as 0.05, then if the actual value was 0.09 and we were off by 0.05 then the interpolation value would be 0.14 and the first digit wouldn't be accurate...

Comment: That is what I mean by saying they can change because of carries.  When you are close, a small change can change many digits.  If the true value is $1.0001$ and you are off $0.0005$ you could read $0.9996$ and there are not any digits truly right.  It seems silly not to say the $1.000$ or $0.999$ are not right in this case.  "Number of digits" is a rough way of speaking.  If you want to be precise, you need to use $\pm$ error notation, which frees you from problems with carries.  In the last example, your measurement would be $0.9996 \pm 0.0005$

Comment: I was told that my value for h was wrong and needed to be adjusted to fit the $(i-.5)h\leq x <(i+.5)h$ shift... Any ideas on that? Thank you

Comment: It looks to me like $h$ is specified in the question as $0.1$

Comment: That's what I think too. I think it is right. Thanks